# Setting the oauth "Authorization"header in Java - Android

Tags: android, oauth, header, authorization, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to set the access token with all of my network calls in my Android app.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Token token="
                    + accessToken);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

With this code, however, the header that our server is seeing is "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" - not "AUTHORIZATION".  After pouring over javadocs, I can't figure out how to not get it to append the "HTTP_".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The mapping of Authorization to HTTP_AUTHORIZATION is part of the [CGI Specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875) and happens on the server.